# How can I use unittest in python to test function that uses set.pop() when calculating the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, python-unittest

I want to test a function that uses `set.pop(`) when calculating the output.

I would like to pop elements by there priority (for example: 'a' will be pop before 'b') but only when running the test.

I thought about changing the pop method inside my function (to pop the minimum value) but this will also change the behavior of the function when it runs regularly (and not with unit tests).

```
import unittest

def using_set(arr):
    res = []
    s = set(arr)
    while len(s):
        res.append(s.pop())

    return ','.join(res)


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_using_set(self):
        self.assertEqual('a,b,g', using_set(['b','a','g']))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Test the behavior of the actual function, not a modified version of it. That said, `using_set` could be much more simply defined as `using_set = lambda s : ','.join(s)`, and you could test it simply by comparing the output both implementations. (Note that while the iteration order of a particular set is arbitrary, it is fixed for the same object, so iterating over it twice will produce the same order each time.)

Comment: Hi @chepner, Thanks for the answer. 
I know that I don't need to use set(), the above code is only for demonstrate my problem, my actual code must use set() because it is part of an algorithm implementation (I use it as part of topological sort).
I understand that I need to test the actual behavior, and my question here is how could I test a function if it could return different outputs for the same input?

Answer (score 0):

The better idea is to write deterministic functions; in this case, that would mean not just using the elements of `s` in the order that `pop` returns them, but to iterate over a sorted sequence of its elements. (Repeatedly mutating the set is inefficient anyway.)

```
def using_set(arr):
    res = []
    s = set(arr)
    for item in sorted(s):
        res.append(item)
    return ','.join(res)
```

If you can't modify `using_set`, then you need to manipulate its return value in a manner consistent with what you would *want* `using_set` to return.

```
self.assertEqual(['a', 'b', 'g'], sorted(using_set(['b', 'a', 'g']).split(,)))
```

(There's no sense re-joining the return-value elements after sorting if you can just specify an unjoined expected value instead.)